# wrong value on mysql INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I am getting the wrong value on gfee and netpay.

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, c.name AS course_name,
s.open_bal AS open_balance, sum(i.amount) AS gross_fee,
sum(i.discount) AS discount, sum(i.amount) - sum(i.discount) AS net_payable,
SUM(r.reg_fee+r.tut_fee+r.other_fee) AS net_recieved,
(sum(i.amount) - sum(i.discount)) - SUM(r.reg_fee+r.tut_fee+r.other_fee) AS balance_due
FROM subscribers s
INNER JOIN courses c on c.id = s.course_id
LEFT JOIN invoices i on i.student_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN recipts r on r.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id;
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean with `wrong`? What do you get and what you expect to be correct?

Comment: @ypercube i am getting 70000 as gross_fee instead of 35000

Comment: Sounds like you have two records in `recipts` for that `student_id`. Maybe you are missing some additional join-condition?

Comment: Don't `JOIN` and then `GROUP and SUM`. First `GROUP and SUM` the `invoices`, `receipts` tables, and then `JOIN` with students.

Comment: @Peter Lang YES right, i am having 2 records in `recipts`

Comment: You probably now have one student with 2 receipts or 2 courses. If you add another course or recipt, the query will show he ows 105000 (or even more!)

Comment: @ypercube yes right i am having 2 records in recipts table, can you update my code and post it as answer, thanks.

Comment: Additionally... You are querying against the the courses and invoices... Is there a correlation between the courses and invoices aside from the student?  If so, what  Is there a course ID on the invoice?  What happens if a person is taking 3 courses, you don't want to show an open invoice associated with all 3 courses of $500 being a total balance of $1500...

Comment: @DRapp invoice is related to students not courses and  student can select only 1 course but can have mutiple invoices and recipts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.id
     , s.name
     , c.name AS course_name
     , s.open_bal AS open_balance
     , igroup.gross_fee
     , igroup.discount
     , igroup.net_payableinvoices
     , rgroup.net_recieved
     , igroup.net_payableinvoices - rgroup.net_recieved
       AS balance_due
FROM students s
INNER JOIN courses c
  on c.id = s.course_id
LEFT JOIN 
  ( SELECT i.student_id
         , SUM(i.amount) AS gross_fee
         , SUM(i.discount) AS discount
         , SUM(i.amount) - sum(i.discount)
           AS net_payableinvoices
    FROM invoices i
    GROUP BY i.student_id
  ) AS igroup
  ON igroup.student_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN 
  ( SELECT r.student_id
         , SUM(r.reg_fee+r.tut_fee+r.other_fee)
           AS net_recieved
    FROM recipts r 
    GROUP BY r.student_id
  ) AS rgroup
  ON rgroup.student_id = s.id
;
```

Comment: Try now (there was a wrong placed `i`). Not sure why you have `fm_invoices` in your error message though.

Comment: its giving balance_due as -15000 instead of 20000 as i am getting `gross_fee: 35000 | discount: 0 | net_payableinvoices: 35000 | net_recieved: 15000 | balance_due: -15000 `

Comment: This is where I was going to go... pre-aggregate all invoices by themselves, receipts by themselves and get one per respective student ID, THEN join to the student...   Very well laid-out.

Comment: hello thanks for great help, how can we replace NULL with 0 and even i want to add open_balance to gross_balance.

Comment: To convert NULLs to zero, replace `expression` with: `COALESCE(expression,0)`

Comment: and how can i add open_balance to gross_balance like this? SUM(i.amount) + s.openbal

Comment: @seoppc: You ant to add another column that will be shown in the in the SELECT? Just add one more row in the first SELECT: `, igroup.gross_fee+s.openbal AS gross_balance`

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of your problem is multiple rows existing in one of the joined tables.

Since you are getting exactly twice your expected value (70000 vs 35000) I would guess that there are two rows in either the `courses` or `recipts` tables with `student_id=22`.

Comment: yes there are 2 rows in recipts but how to fix this issue, and how can i optimize this code better for perfect results?

Comment: Well, you need to figure out which row from the `recipts` table is the right one for your calculation.  Then your join can be updated to `left join recipts r on r.student_id = s.id AND r.something = [filter value]`.

Comment: i want to total of all rows(payment column) in recipts where id(from student table) is equal to student_id(from recipt table), i want to get total payment received from that student.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that 70,000 is double 35,000 is a hugely important clue. You're talking about a `SUM` and you're getting twice what you expected. That suggests strongly that you're joining to twice as many rows as you think you are.

Without knowing the details of your schema it's hard to be specific, but if you're joining to two different rows in `receipts` for each row in `invoices` (for this particular record), you end up with two `35,000` entries included in your sum. Not what you had in mind.

Comment: i want to get the report for all students based on invoices, recipts as you can see in my sql query, let me know if you need anything from me, thanks.